# Install4j - advance form component's customization won't apply while on upgrade

Tags: install4j

In our installer we have multiple form components in which we hide some inner options in case the user have choose a specific option.

For example: In this screen -  this is the default displayed options.

[image]

If the user choose different *Authentication* than the default *SQL Server Authentication* (Windows Authentication), than the installer hides the *User Name* & *Password* fields.

The problem happens while on upgrade. If the user previously choose the *Windows Authentication* option - the displayed screen will be like this:

[image]

It's not good, because while connecting with *Windows Authentication* the user input *User Name* & *Password* shouldn't be presented.
The Authentication input is defined as *Combo-Box* & have the *Selection change script* property like this:

```
if (selectedItem.equals("Windows Authentication")) {
    ((JTextField)formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("1418").getConfigurationObject()).setText("");
}

formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("1418").setVisible(!selectedItem.equals("Windows Authentication"));
formEnvironment.getFormComponentById("1677").setVisible(!selectedItem.equals("Windows Authentication"));
```

Basically I do understand why it won't work on upgrade - since it work by selection trigger, it won't be applied by default by the installer.

Is there any way applying this logic also upon upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute the same logic in the "Visibility script" properties of the "User name" and "Password" form components. You don't have the "selectedItem" parameter there, but you can query the variable that is bound to the "Authentication" form component, i.e. `context.getVariable("variableName")`.